# Google Visualization Not Working?

Tags: javascript, visualization, candlestick-chart

I have the following code to draw candlestick visualization. But the visualization is not generated. I am unable to trace error using Error Console!.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});

function drawVisualization() {
   // Populate the data table.
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number');
      data.addColumn('number');
      data.addColumn('number');
      data.addColumn('number');   
      data.setValue(0, 0,'Mon');
      data.setValue(0, 1, '2');
      data.setValue(0,2,'6');
      data.setValue(0,3,'8');
      data.setValue(0,4,'10');
      data.setValue(1, 0,'Mon');
      data.setValue(1, 1, '2');
      data.setValue(1,2,'6');
      data.setValue(1,3,'8');
      data.setValue(1,4,'10');
    // Draw the chart.
     var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {legend:'none', width:600, height:400});
    }

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
  </script>
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated!
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

1 - You need to add rows to the table before you try and set their values.

2 - Values for index 1,2,3 and 4 have to be numbers instead of strings since Columns 1,2,3,4 are of a numeric type

```
...
  // Populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number');
  data.addColumn('number');
  data.addColumn('number');
  data.addColumn('number');
  //Add new rows first
  data.addRow();
  data.addRow();
  data.setValue(0, 0, 'Mon');
  data.setValue(0, 1, 2);
  data.setValue(0, 2, 6);
  data.setValue(0, 3, 8);
  data.setValue(0, 4, 10);
  data.setValue(1, 0, 'Mon');
  data.setValue(1, 1, 2);
  data.setValue(1, 2, 6);
  data.setValue(1, 3, 8);
  data.setValue(1, 4, 10);
  // Draw the chart.
...
```

Here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/WcKFf/2/